# How to integrated into testlink and redmine

Tags: plugins, integration, redmine, testlink

If someone has integrated TestLink and Redmine before, please help. I am unable to find Redmine integration plugins, so any assistance would be appreciated.

If someone has integrated TestLink and Redmine before, please help. I am unable to find Redmine integration plugins, so any assistance would be appreciated..